# Find a set of values of the constant k for which a 4th degree polynomial has four real roots?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

[image]

I am having trouble in figuring out the best approach on how to start off this question. Hope somebody has an idea.

Comment: Where are the critical points?  If you sketch the graph roughly you'll see that you want the two minima to be below the $x-$axis and the local max to be  above.

Answer (score 1):

If for some $k$, the polynomial function
$$ f(x)=3x^4+4x^3-12x^2+k$$
has the maximum possible number of four distinct roots, then between any two distinct roots, there is a local extremum, more precisely, first a minimum, then a maximum, then a minimum again (because $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to \pm\infty$). Apparently, the values at the minima must  be negative and at the maximum positive, and as long as we respect these sign rules, there will be four distinct real roots.

The extrema of $f$ are at the roots of $f'(x)=12x^3+12x^2-24x=12x(x-1)(x+2)$, i.e., at $x=0$, $x=1$, $x=-2$.  We compute $f(-2)=k-32$, $f(0)=k$, $f(1)=k-5$, so from the preceding remarks arrive at the condition
$$0<k<5. $$